# Why does my Spring PropertySource annotation fail on the encoding attribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a new Spring web app and I'm following a pattern that has worked well for earlier web apps. I have a web application configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example" })
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class WebApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```

When I start the web app (under Tomcat), I get the following error:

```
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
    Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.WebApplicationConfiguration];
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    Attribute 'encoding' not found in attributes for annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse (ConfigurationClassParser.java:187)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    Attribute 'encoding' not found in attributes for annotation
    [org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource]
```

I haven't needed to specify the `encoding` attribute on the `@PropertySource` annotation in earlier web apps, so I'm not sure why error is showing up now. Anyway, I tried the following:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

... and this made no difference, ie. I got the same error. This suggests to me that the underlying cause might not be the `@PropertySource` annotation. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong

Comment: Looks like mixing jars from different version of Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum Wow, good call. Feel free to add this as answer. How did you figure it out? Or have you seen this before?

Comment: Errors like that are generally a result of mixing jars from different versions. I.e. a annotation processor expecting something being part of the annotation that isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors like this are generally a sign of mixing jars from different versions of Spring. In this case the annotation processor for the `@PropertySource` annotation expects the `encoding` property to be there.

However at runtime it isn't there and hence it produces the error.

You want to check your (transitive) dependencies for conflicting versions (or versions you haven't managed explicitly).

Comment: dave, Run 'mvn dependency:tree' to see the conflict, if you use maven

Comment: I use `gradle` and by inadvertently using the `compile` dependency instead of `compileOnly`, ended up with the spring `jar` files both in my `war` file and in the Tomcat `lib` directory, resulting in my issue.